# How does Wikipedia derive the formula for the Asymptotic Mean Integrated Square Error (AMISE)?

Tags: calculus, statistics, asymptotics, mean-square-error

In [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#Bandwidth_selection) they show that the Mean Integrated Square Error (MISE) is given by
$$\mathrm{MISE}(h)=\mathrm{E}\left[\int(\hat{f}_h(x)-f(x))^2dx\right],$$
where $f(x)$ is the real density function, $\hat{f}_h(x)$ is the estimate given by
$$\hat{f}_h(x)=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^nK\left(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\right),$$
$K$ is the kernel, $x_i$ are sample points, $n$ is the number of samples and $h$ is the bandwidth.

They then show that the Asymptotic MISE (AMISE) is given by
$$\mathrm{AMISE}(h)=\frac{R(K)}{nh}+\frac{1}{4}m_2(K)^2h^4R(f''),$$
where
$$R(g)=\int g(x)^2dx,$$
for a function $g(x)$,
$$m_2(K)=\int x^2K(x)dx$$
and $f''(x)$ is the second derivative of $f(x)$.

My question is how is the formula for $\mathrm{AMISE}$ derived? I understand terms of of order $o\left(\frac{1}{nh} + h^4\right)$ are neglected. But other than that I cannot see how this formula is derived.

Comment: See eg: https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/718/NonParametrics1.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading that now. Looks like it's exactly what I was looking for.